# Resistance of superconductors

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, superconductivity

Is the resistance of superconductor,in reality, actually zero? Or is it too low (negligible resistance)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20947/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101379/2451

Comment: Perhaps search the web for superconductivity.